# Cartesian product with specific order

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I need to output cartesian product of N lists in specific order.

I know how to build products in "default" order:

Given sets `(a, b, c), (x, y), (1, 2, 3)`, first I produce `ax1`, then iterate over last set to get `ax2`, `ax3`, then change element in the second set and iterate over the last set again for `ay1`, `ay2`, `ay3`, etc...

The order I need should not go for the `N`-th element in any set, before producing products of `N-1` elements

Desired result is `ax1, ax2, ay1, ay2, bx1, bx2, by1, by2, ax3, ay3, bx3, by3, cx1, cx2, cx3, cy1, cy2, cy3`. See, I don't get `ax3` (containing 3rd element from `(1, 2, 3)`), before producing all products with 2nd elements.

My current algorithm is:

- trunace sets to length `1`
- generate products
- truncate sets to length `2`
- generate products
- remove duplicates, preserving order
- ...
- truncate sets to length `max length of all sets`
- generate products
- remove duplicates, preserving order

Each step "generate products" also generates all products from the previous step, so I have to remove them

Is it the better algorith to get desired order? Does it have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this order has a name, but this seems to do what you ask for without having to remove repeated items.

```
from itertools import islice, product, zip_longest

def specific_order_cartesian(lists):
    its = [[lst[0]] for lst in lists]
    yield tuple(lst[0] for lst in lists)

    for column in list(islice(zip_longest(*lists), 1, None)):
        for i, p in reversed(list(enumerate(column))):
            if p is None:
                continue

            yield from product(
                *(
                    (p,) if j == i else its[j]
                    for j in range(len(lists))
                )
            )

            its[i].append(p)


print(list(specific_order_cartesian(
    [('a', 'b', 'c',), ('x', 'y'), (1, 2, 3)]
)))
```